Get attached lsp server name
I am trying to show on lualine the current attached LSP server name. I don't want to install plugins in order to do this so I am searching for a way to do it with the Neovim API. I've read the docs and searched online but I didn't found anything useful.
Any help is appreciated.

The vim.lsp.get_clients() function gets the active clients. If you prefix it with buf_ it only gets the active clients of the current buffer:

The vim.lsp.buf_… functions perform operations for all LSP clients
attached to the given buffer.

So you could do something like:
:lua =vim.lsp.buf_get_clients()[1].name

to print it within nvim or to use it in Lua:
vim.lsp.buf_get_clients()[1].name

However, more than one LSP-client can be attached to a buffer. The [1] only gets the first one. So you need to check the length to handle cases were 0 or more than 1 client is attached.
